# How do I deal with migration name clashes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, migration, rails-migrations

I installed a shopping cart gem (Piggybak), that created a migration called `create_orders...`...but I am no longer using that gem, and have added a migration to drop all tables related to piggybak.

However, I am trying to roll my own shopping cart and when I created a new migration called `create_order` even though it has a different timestamp, I am getting this error:

```
$ rake db:migrate
[RailsAdmin] RailsAdmin initialization disabled by default. Pass SKIP_RAILS_ADMIN_INITIALIZER=false if you need it.
rake aborted!
Multiple migrations have the name CreateOrders
```

So...I renamed the migration to `create_non_piggybak_orders` and am now getting this error:

```
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

uninitialized constant CreateNonPiggybakOrders/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize'
```

What's the best approach to handling this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the migration file and change the name of the class to match the file in camelcase, that is:

`class CreateNonPiggybakOrders < ActiveRecord::Migration`

Comment: ugh...but that's such a hideous table name. I assume I would then have to change my model name - so it matches, right? Also, every instance of an association would be `@user.nonpiggybakorders` right?

Comment: I don't have to change the name of the table. Just the name of the class of the migration. Thanks!

Comment: You got it. That's exactly what I meant.