# Multiple migrations have the name *, after renaming tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created a model `Upload`, later renamed it to `UploadFile`. 
Then created a new model on name `"Upload"`
So now there are two same migrations with `"CreateUpload"`

Error in console:
`ActiveRecord::DuplicateMigrationNameError: Multiple migrations have the name CreateUpload`

How to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Delete the already existed **`create_upload.rb`** in your **`db/migrate`** folder and generate the model again.

This should resolve the Issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can directly delete the duplicate migration file from the **db/migrate/XXXX_duplicate_file_name.rb**.
And run the rake db:migrate command again. This works just fine!
It worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve that problem:

- Delete the duplicate model from **db:migrate** folder.
- Run the **rake db:migrate** command again.(Everything will be migrated)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer will break your migrations if you ever intend to run all migrations from scratch again, and have successive migrations that depend on the create table one existing.  If you delete the original migration, any dependent successive migrations will now fail.  I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157887/how-do-i-deal-with-migration-name-clashes) is better, and won't break the whole chain of migrations.

In my case, my migration sequence was:

1. Create table
2. Create reference (foreign key) between new table and another
3. Rename table
4. Create table (with first table's original name)

Like the OP, I had the same problem with duplicate names and so deleted the migration from Step 1.  However, when I went to run the migrations from scratch (I was changing from MySQL to Postgresql), it was failing, since now Step 2 was referencing a table that didn't exist.  In the end I had to manually re-create the deleted migration (with appropriate timestamp) and use the technique in the linked question to make everything run smoothly from beginning to end.